# Приложение не просчитывает выражения

Tags: android

Приложение должно просчитывает среднее арифметическое population выбранных пользователем стран

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String KEY_AVERAGE = "average";
    String[] countries = {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
    int[] population = {6770000, 2300000, 500000, 6310000, 7000000};
    Button btnSubmit;
    int sum;
    ListView countriesList;
    int average;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Map<String, Integer> countryData = new HashMap<>(countries.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            countryData.put(countries[i], population[i]);
        }

        countriesList = findViewById(R.id.countriesList);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);
        countriesList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        countriesList.setAdapter(adapter);


        btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view)  {

                   SparseBooleanArray checked = countriesList.getCheckedItemPositions();
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
                    sum += population[checked.keyAt(i)];
                }
            }
            average = sum / countriesList.getCheckedItemCount();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("KEY_AVERAGE", average);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Main3Activity

```
public class Main3Activity extends Main2Activity {

    TextView tvView;
    int average;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);

        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        average = mIntent.getExtras().getInt(Main2Activity.KEY_AVERAGE, average);
        tvView.setText("Average: " + average);
    }
}
```

В Main3Activity вместо среднеего арифметического отображается 0. Как сделать, чтобы приложение заработало правильно ?